# Microsoft word wildcard find and replace using ctrl h function

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

Hi I am a complete novice with Microsoft word wildcard function using ctrl h

I need some assistance with finding all capital letters in a word document and insert line break before each capital letter

Example

Perfect party wear Classic black jacket Open front Collarless

I need to change the above to:

Perfect party wear

Classic black jacket

Open front Collarless

I have tried using Find what:<[A-Z][a-z]{2,}> Replace with ^13 and it replaces the all the words that start with a capital letter with a line break instead of inserting a line break before the capital letter.

I would really appreciate some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Find what: <[A-Z][a-z]{2,}>
Replace with: ^p^&
Options: Use wildcards
```

`^p` is a paragraph mark (end of paragraph, same as typing <Enter>, not the caracter `¶`). `^&` means "the text what was found". Press the button `Special` with the cursor in the `Find what` or the `Replace with` fields to see (some of) the available specialties.

Comment: Some of the text is in a table and this doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Edited the answer. Use `^p` instead of `^13`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It there a way to remove the extra carriage breaks?

Comment: What is "extra"? For example, I routinely replace (no "Use wildcards"): `^w^p` with `^p` (delete white space at the end of paragraphs), then repeatedly `^p^p` with `^p` (delete empty paragraphs) until there are no more empty paragraphs. This may or may not suit your style of formatting. And in Word a paragraph mark (what you get when you press Enter) and a line break (what you get when you press Shift+Enter) are very different things.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved the problem, so that future readers may know that it worked.